# MATLAB function fminunc generates errors

Tags: matlab

I am facing an error when using the function **fminunc** in the context of a maximum-likelihood estimation. I am afraid that it is very straight forward however my experience with MATLAB is very limited.

The function "normal" contains the log-likelihood function. I seek to estimate the expectation and std. deviation of a normal distribution given the observations stored in the variable x.

```
function f = normal(X, theta)

mean = theta(1);
sigma = theta(2);
z = (X-mean)./sigma;

f = -(sum(-log(sigma) -(1/2).*z.^2 ));
```

I basically execute the following code:

```
theta = [1,1]

f = @(theta)normal(x, theta)

[est, fval, exitflag, output, grad, hessian] = fminunc('normal', x, theta)
```

The error is the following:

> Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See MATLAB R14SP2 Release
>   Notes, Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details.
>
> > In createOptionFeedback at 34
> >       In prepareOptionsForSolver at 31
> >       In fminunc at 157 
> >     Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See MATLAB R14SP2 Release
> >     Notes, Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details. 
> >     In fminunc at 203 
> >     Error using feval
> >     Undefined function 'normal' for input arguments of type 'double'.
>
> Error in fminunc (line 254)
>           f = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
>
> Caused by:
>       Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FMINUNC cannot continue.

Unfortunately the manual did not help me to fix the code. Calling

```
[est, fval, exitflag, output, grad, hessian] = fminunc(f, x, theta)
```

did not help either. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called `fminunc` with the wrong sintax, please refer to the documentation.

A way to fix your code is by defining the function `normal` to accept only one parameter: `theta`.

```
function f = normal(theta)

global X

mean = theta(1);
sigma = theta(2);
z = (X-mean)./sigma;
f = -(sum(-log(sigma) -(1/2).*z.^2 ));
```

and call `fminunc` with

```
global X
X = randn(100, 1);  % A possible time series.
theta0 = [1,1];
[est, fval, exitflag, output, grad, hessian] = fminunc(@normal, theta0);
```

Comment: why `global` and not anonymous function?

Comment: Its a way of proceeding. Other possibilities includes: a struct with `theta` and `X`, a nested function where everything is defined, a file identifier, ... . I think that it is up to the user choose the best method for its specific case.